# No files in home on Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku

I have problem to deploy a Django application on Heroku. There is nothing in home after a git push. I don't think that the problem is git because I can push to repository on github.

```
(23:43:01 (venv)user@host ~/path $ git push heroku 4heroku
Everything up-to-date
(23:43:31 (venv)user@host ~/path $ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3486
~ $ ls
~ $ ls -la
total 8
drwx------  2 u12545 12545 4096 Mar 26 23:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root  4096 Oct 31  2011 ..
~ $ exit
(23:44:16 (venv)user@host ~/path $ heroku logs
......
2013-03-26T23:34:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by email@yahoo.co.uk
2013-03-26T23:34:05+00:00 heroku[run.8328]: Awaiting client
2013-03-26T23:34:05+00:00 heroku[run.8328]: Starting process with command `bash`
2013-03-26T23:34:06+00:00 heroku[run.8328]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T23:34:39+00:00 heroku[run.8328]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-03-26T23:34:40+00:00 heroku[run.8328]: State changed from up to complete
2013-03-26T23:34:40+00:00 heroku[run.8328]: Process exited with status 0
2013-03-26T23:44:00+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by email@yahoo.co.uk
2013-03-26T23:44:02+00:00 heroku[run.3486]: Starting process with command `bash`
2013-03-26T23:44:02+00:00 heroku[run.3486]: Awaiting client
2013-03-26T23:44:02+00:00 heroku[run.3486]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-26T23:44:16+00:00 heroku[run.3486]: Process exited with status 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a different push, if you want to deploy a branch that is not the `master` branch. According to [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code):

> Branches pushed to Heroku other than master will be ignored by this
>   command. If you’re working out of another branch locally, you can
>   either merge to master before pushing, or specify that you want to
>   push your local branch to a remote master. To push a branch other than
>   master, use this syntax:

```
$ git push heroku yourbranch:master
```